WACK can't fetch list of approved APIs
I've written a UWP app in C#.NET.  I've tested it, and want to publish it to the App Store, so I need to run the Windows App Certification Kit (WACK) on it.  Most of the tests pass, but the Supported API test fails consistently, always saying: The supported APIs test detected the following errors: Unable to get the list of approved APIs.
Note that this doesn't mean that I'm using any unapproved APIs.  In fact, near as I can tell, WACK hasn't checked the APIs I'm using at all, because it's unable to get the list of what I -can-use.  This seems to be a clear bug in WACK - how can I pass the test if it can't figure out what the 'passing' and 'failing' criteria would be and actually run the test?
Note that this has occurred with my VPN on as well as off, and that I've updated Windows to the latest version as of yesterday.
This happens whether or not I run WACK in administrator mode.
What can I do?

Here's the relevant bit from WACK's output:

FAILED - Supported APIs
Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
Unable to get the list of approved APIs.
Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK
for Microsoft Store apps violates the Microsoft Store certification
requirements.
How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not
part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps. If the DLL listed is
an allowable redistributable from a NuGET package, SDK or other
toolkit, did you forget to add the DLL to your app? Please note, apps
that are built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled
(where applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull
in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and
with .NET Native enabled if applicable. See the link below for more
information: [link]


You'll note that the 'How to fix' section says to identify the API that's not part of the Windows SDK... but the error message doesn't identify any APIs at all.

Here's some information about my app and system from WACK:
App Architecture: x64
Kit Version: 10.0.26100.1742
OS Version: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19045.0)
OS Architecture: x64

Some details about the Windows SDK from my Project Properties:
- Target Version is Build 26100 

- Min version is Build 17763

I tried putting the Min Version to 22000 (first Windows 11 build), but I'm running Windows 10, so WACK didn't run all the tests.  I tried various Windows 10 options for the Minimum version, and just stuck with the one I'd originally been using, 17763.

Hi @Ken White, thanks for responding.  Can you help me understand what you mean by off-site vendor service?  WACK isn't a service, it's an app that you run against a package you've written.  SO has lots of help on it for actually writing the packages, and so it stands to reason that someone here has had experience with WACK and may have run into this issue before.  I have posted on Microsoft forums as well, but the quality of the forums and the community there isn't nearly as high as that here on SO.

Is it packaged in release mode?

@JunjieZhu-MSFT, yes it is packaged in release mode.  Thanks for responding.
